# What is the smallest object that can spin?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

A molecule can rotate in three-dimensional space. Can a single proton spin? Are there smaller units of matter that can rotate?

Comment: I always had and still have the same question. I guess it is the quantum nature of stuff that makes the question meaningless. But without entering in the spin description, which is not the rotation we intend here, why exactly an H atom or proton cannot be *at least conceived* in rotation? I hope we'll find the answer here.

Comment: @Alchimista in answering your question, to measure a rotation you need to define fixed axis on the object, The proton is a quantum mechanical entity, has no fixed surface, due to the probabilistic nature of the  (conceptual) orbitals of the quarks and sea of quarks antiquarks and gluons that compose it. It was assigned spin 1/2 in order to agree with data  and angular momentum conservation in interactions and decays.

Comment: Talking about the classical concept of spin, in 3D space, a *point-particle* cannot spin. Only a set of *two* points (or more), of different positions, could spin. It doesn't matter how close or how far they are, as long as they don't have the same position, they *can* spin. So, as long as a "small" "particle" is actually made of at least two separate "point-particles", it could spin. I don't think the nature of particles, pointness-wise, is fully settled in modern physics.

Comment: @JuanPerez So all rotation is fundamentally translation?

Comment: @2080 From a classical point of view, yes. Any rotation consists merely of translation of one or more points while satisfying certain restrictions like keeping their distance constant. A single point can't rotate nor does it have any 'orientation'. Going beyond the classical, however, we may (or may not) find points that do have properties with some kind of orientation and therefore can be rotated, somehow. I assumed this last part was not what you cared about in your question.

Comment: So conservation of angular momentum is solely derived from the usual translational conservation of momentum acting on multiple connected bodies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - protons have a so-called "spin quantum number". It is 1/2 for protons. Protons are made of quarks, which also have a 1/2 spin quantum number. In fact all known fermions (which are what make up ordinary matter) have spin 1/2. Spin 1/2 means the particle must be fully rotated twice to end up in its original configuration.

You can read more about spin quantum numbers on the Wikipedia article for [spin-1/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-%C2%BD).

Comment: Spin (intrinsic angular momentum) does not correspond to actual rotation on an axis, how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

If what you meant by smallest particles was particles having the smallest mass, one can list the followings. But before doing so, bear in mind that unlike what you asked in the question, spin doesn't exactly correspond to anything familiar from the classical mechanics.

Think about an electron and it has spin $\pm1/2$, since it's an elementary particle and have no internal structure they are point-like and it's not meaningful to define classical rotation of a point-like particle around its own axis (try to imagine a point rotating around it's own axis, you'll get what I mean). Spin, unlike classical rotation, is an intrinsic form of angular momentum.

[Some of the smallest particles and their spins (referring directly to your question):](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_particles#Quarks)  , check out photon, gluon, electron neutrino and up quark.

Comment: Same comment as that by Nihsr Karve to the answer written by @Allure

Comment: I disagree, our definition of spin is the same but it's the same with thousands of physicist too, this doesn't make the answer the same. Question asks what's the smallest object that can have spin. Wikipedia link partially provides the answer, I don't see how this is the same with @Nihsr Karve 's answer. On the basis of OP's misunderstanding, I had given the example of an electron and explained why it would be wrong to assume it (classically) rotates, I don't see this in Nihsr Karve 's answer too.

Comment: Monopole, I see that what you wrote is correct. It is the classical answer one get. Perhaps it satisfies OP - anyway s/he likely use spin as 3D rotation - but somewhat not me, which I think I have the same question nevertheless (as you can see from my comment to the question). Say I do think to an electron as represented by its wave function (perhaps norm squared to make it more physical). Why we cannot think of it rotating? Merely because it has no influences whatsoever?